# building FMU .so for modelica / Reference-FMUs does not seem to work

Tags: build

I wanted to learn how to make an FMU .so file,  but i keep getting segfault errors with fmusim

I did the following steps.

closed the repo to /some_dir/
unzip BouncingBall.fmu to /some_dir/bb_unzip/
cd to /some_dir/bb_unzip/sources/
gcc -I. -c all.c -shared -o ../binaries/linux64/BouncingBall.so which I assumed would remake the .so
rezip with remade .so file to BouncingBall2.fmu
fmusim BouncingBall2.fmu
but this results in a segmentation fault.
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555556e6e3 in FMI2Instantiate ()

I was able to make all FMUs successfully using /some_dir/CMakeLists.txt and browse the files that come from that, but I guess I was hoping there was a more straight forward way to build a .so file from source.

Any suggestions?